# Area between two circles equal to half the area of one of the circles

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, definite-integrals

[image: Figure 1]

Consider the above picture, where you would want to find a value for $r$, depending on $R$ so that the conjoint area (marked gray) is equal to **half the area** of the $\color{darkorange}{\text{orange circle}}$, i.e.

$$A(r) = \frac{1}{2}\pi R^2$$

#### Come up with a way to find $r$, **if** the $\color{blue}{\text{blue circle's}}$ centre is located on the perimeter of the $\color{darkorange}{\text{orange circle}}$.

---

I'm okay with using Mathematica if necessary, I just can't seem to find a way to solve my problem. Also allow me to *streamline* the wording of the problem.

### Problem worded differently

If you have a circle with radius $R$, and you attach another circle, with its centre, on the perimeter of the first circle. Find the radius $r$ (see first image) for the second circle such that the area between the circles is $50\%$ of the area of the first circle.

[image]

Comment: Typically this problem is solved using an angle as unknown.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Hmm, interesting. I'll try this, care to add *which* angle though?

Comment: I added a new wording for the problem, and clarified that I can use Mathematica if required.

Comment: I referred to a solution without calculus.

Comment: Best looking question I have seen from a long time (+1)

Comment: I elaborate what I said in the first comment: see my answer.

Comment: With no loss of generality, $R=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C_1$ be our $\color{blue}{\text{blue circle}}$, and $C_2$ our $\color{darkorange}{\text{orange circle}}$ with the following coordinates. Note that $C_2$ lies at $(0,R)$ which is an important detail for this problem.

[image]

Our two circles' equations are

$\begin{eqnarray}
C_1&:& x^2+y^2 &= R^2 \tag{1}\\
C_2&:& (x-R)^2+y^2 &= r^2 \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ and solving for $x$ we get

$$(x-R)^2+(R^2-x^2) = r^2 \\ x_1 = \dfrac{2R^2-r^2}{2R}$$

So what did we just find? We found the $x$-coordinate at which the two circles intersect.
Using the formula to find an area for a [circular segment](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html). Let $R'$ be a radius, and $d$ a distance from a circle's centre to a chord. *For our case, our chord would be a vertical line going through the intersection points of our circles.*

$$A(R',d) = R'^2\cdot\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{d}{R'}\right) - d\sqrt{R'^2-d^2}$$

Using this, and plugging in respectively value for our circles we get the following

$$A(R,x_1) = R^2\cdot\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x_1}{R}\right) - x_1\sqrt{R^2-x_1^2}$$

So where are we now? We've calculated the shaded area below, and we need to find $d$ so that we can do the same for the other [circular segment](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html).

[image]

Well, we know that the distance between our circles is $R$. So why not put $d = R-x_1$. Hence,

$$A(r,d) = r^2\cdot\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{d}{r}\right) - d\sqrt{r^2-d^2}$$

This would mean our $A_{total} = A(R,x_1) + A(r,d)$. Writing this out becomes tedious, but using Mathematica gives,

$$A_{total} = r^2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{r^2}{2R\cdot r}\right) + R^2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{2R^2-r^2}{2R^2}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{r^2\cdot 2R(2R+r)}$$

Now, using our $A_{total}$ we can find values for $r$ by specifying $R$ and the area ratio you want. I.e.

If $R = 2$ and you want the area between the circles to equal half of $C_1$'s area, you would put:

$$R = 2: A_{total} = \frac{1}{2}\pi\cdot R^2 = 2\pi$$

Let Mathematica calculate $A_{total}$ numerically after specifying $R$, and you will find it gives you two solutions. Use the **positive numerical solution** and that's the radius you were looking for.

**NB!** By trying different values for $R$ and dividing the result $r$ with $R$, respectively, you'll find $\frac{R}{r} \approx 1.15872847 \ldots$. (OEIS [A133731](http://oeis.org/A133731))

And as such, for this particular problem, the radius $r$ is always near $1.16\cdot R$ length units.

Answer (score 3):

I don't use analytic geometry.

Let $A$ and $B$ be the points of intersection of the circles and $C$ the center of the circle of radius $r$.

Let $x=\angle ACB$ our unknown. Then $$r=2R \cos \frac x2$$ Simple facts about geometry and trigonometry give the equation $$\sin x - x \cos x= \frac \pi2$$ so $x$ is approximately $1.9056957$ and $r/R$ is approximately $1.1587285$ .

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without calculus.  Draw the line AB.  The lens is composed of two [circular segments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment), one generated by each circle.  If the center of the small circle is $C$ and the center of $AB$ is $D$, you have $AC=r, AD=\sqrt{R^2-(R-CD)^2}=\sqrt{r^2-CD^2}. $  Once you find the coordinates of $A$, you can just integrate $\sqrt{r^2-x^2}-(R-\sqrt{R^2-x^2})$ from $A$ to $B$ and have the area.  This is much harder than using geometry, but you can get there.

Comment: This is interesting. I will attempt this later, but do you know how to do this with the aid of calculus?

Comment: See my update.  I missed that the center of the small circle was on the large circle before