# Can anyone explain this step from Wolfram|MathWorld

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

*Not sure if I used the correct tags*

In my search for an answer to my most [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047132/area-between-two-circles-equal-to-half-the-area-of-one-of-the-circles), which I will try add an answer to, I came across a [good article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) from **MathWorld**.

> Let two circles of radii R and r and centered at $(0,0)$ and $(d,0)$ intersect in a region shaped like an assymetric lens. The equations for the two circles are:
>
> $x^2+y^2=R^2 \\ (x-d)^2+y^2=r^2$
>
> Combining them we have,
>
> $x = \dfrac{d^2-r^2+R^2}{2d}$
>
> $\color{red}{\textit{The chord connecting the cusps of the lens therefore has half-length }\textbf{y }\textit{given by plugging }\textbf{x }\\\textit{back in to obtain}}$
>
> $y^2 = \dfrac{4d^2R^2-(d^2-r^2+R^2)^2}{4d^2}$

In particular I get confused where he says we get that the chord is half-length **y**. (This confuses me very much, **y** to me is an arbitrary value for our combined function)

---

Question 1: What does the $x$ mean to us, geometrically or otherwise, in equation **(5)**?

Question 2: How come the chord is half length **y**, after solving for $x$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Write down your question pointing exactly what the problem is. Linking for question isn't well received here as later links can disappear.

Comment: what is your question? (what do you want to calculate?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 1: $x$ is the x-coordinate of the point where the circles intersect. Subtract
$x^2+y^2=R^2$ from $(x-d)^2+y^2=r^2$ to get
$$
-2xd+d^2=r^2-R^2
$$
Then rearrange to get $x$.

Answer 2: Here $y$ is the height of the intersection above the $x$ axis, so it's half the length of the chord, which goes from the intersection above the $x$ axis, to the intersection below the $x$ axis.